# Dynamic Allocation with pointers c++

Tags: c++

```
Transaction *trans = new Transaction[MAX_NUM];
int currentnum;


addtrans(string balance, double amt){

    trans[currentnum] = new Transaction(balance, amt);
    currentnum ++;
}

//constructor

Transaction(string type, double amt){

      Transtype = type;
       Transamt = amt;
 }
```

I have created a pointer to an array.

I'm trying to send balance and amt to the array, but I am getting the error 'no match for 'operator=' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Transaction *trans = new Transaction[MAX_NUM];
```

This gives you a pointer to an array of `Transaction` objects.

```
trans[currentnum] = new Transaction(balance, amt);
```

This tries to assign to a `Transaction` object in your array, but the `new Transaction(...)` call returns a ***pointer*** to a `Transaction`, and pointers are not the data element type for the array, so this won't compile.

You could say:

```
trans[currentnum] = Transaction(balance, amt);
```

Or, you could do this:

```
Transaction** trans = new (Transaction*)[MAX_NUM];
trans[currentnum] = new Transaction(balance, amt);
```

But it's almost certainly better to use:

```
std::vector<Transaction> trans(MAX_NUM);
```

If you really must have `MAX_NUM` default-constructed elements, or better yet...

```
std::vector<Transaction> trans;
```

And just `.push_back(Transaction(balance,amt))` as you go, so you basically don't have to worry about any `MAX_NUM` or indexing off the end of the container.  If you have a C++11 compiler you can use `.emplace_back(balance, amt)` for better performance and direct in-container construction of the Transaction object..

Comment: @user3457835: you're welcome.  Do try to get used to `vector` as quickly as you can though - it's a little weird at first but will massively simplify your code and make for more robust programs, and help you get ready for using `std::map` which is extremely cool....

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<Transaction> trans;
trans.reserve(MAX_NUM);
```

and `addtrans` can be basically be reduced to:

```
trans.emplace_back(balance, amt);
```

Comment: In that case it should be `std::vector<Transaction*>`

Comment: Yes because it looks like there is no default constructor for class Transaction.

Comment: @aruisdante, well, my point is that he can avoid dynamic allocation at all, so no, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks Jeffffrey, but the problem is I haven't learned vector yet. I would at best like to stick with these terms.

Comment: @tmp: if there wasn't a default constructor, `new Transaction[MAX_NUM];` would not have compiled....

Comment: @Jefffrey: I know that there is no such requirement for std::vector but if your class has defined parametrized constructor and not defined default constructor(and it would not be generated by compiler as well) , so there would be compilation error. You can verify by yourself. Hope now you get what i meant...

Comment: "`std::vector<Transaction> trans(MAX_NUM);` ...and... `trans.emplace_back(balance, amt);`", no - because passing `MAX_NUM` to the `std::vector` constructor is creating that many elements, with `emplace_back` adding even more rather than populating the existing default-constructed elements with meaningful values.

Comment: There is a default constructor, I didn't include it.

Comment: @TonyD: yes now i get it....i missed that part...as new operator call constructor..

Comment: Sweet... +1 from me.  Cheers.